# Моя задача вывести в консоль любые символы в виде системы координат. Хочу вывести в консоль систему координат, где "2" условно ось Y, "3" - ось X

Tags: c++

```
# include <iostream>
# include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int v = 0;v < 20;v++)// 20 символов "2" в ряд с пропуском 11 строки для ее заполнения "3"
    {
        while (v < 10 && v > 10)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 14; a++)
            {
             cout << " ";
             }
        cout << "2" << endl;
        }
    }
    
    
    for (int g = 0; g < 15; g++) // строка "3"
    {
        cout << " 3";
        
        if (g == 29)
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Хочу вывести в консоль систему координат, где "2" условно говоря ось Y, "3" - ось X. В консоль выводит 10 рядов "2", далее строка "3", и все, в некоторых случаях когда я использовал другие варианты (for, if) выводило просто строку "3". Я не могу себя даже новичком назвать, пытаюсь просто понять логику циклов, условий

Comment: попробуйте создать и привести [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я правильно понял — вам надо что-то вроде [этого](https://ideone.com/syzFGA)?

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 31; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 15)
            for(int j = 0; j < 31; ++j)
                cout << (j == 15 ? '+' : '-');
        else
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 15; ++j) cout << ' ';
            cout << '|';
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. А не могли бы вы подробнее рассказать что происходит в этих скобках  ```cout << (j == 15 ? '+' : '-');```

Comment: Выводим `'-'` во всез знакоместах, кроме 15-го, где выводим `'+'`...